# Store a string produced by a function on a variable

Tags: c, string

The code below let's you enter a number and convert it to its words form. For instance an input of 100 will result to an output of one hundred. The next step I need to do is to count the number of letters on the word form of the number. How can I store the value of convertToWords function onto a variable so it can be an input variable for the next line of codes which will count the number of letters.

This is the code for converting words to numbers

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 20
// strings at index 0 is not used, it is to make array
// indexing simple
char* one[] = { "", "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ",
                "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ",
                "nine ", "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ",
                "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ",
                "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ",
                "nineteen "
              };
// strings at index 0 and 1 are not used, they is to
// make array indexing simple
char* ten[] = { "", "", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ",
                "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ",
                "ninety "
              };
char * numToWords(int n, char* s, char *str, int len)
{
    memset(str,0,len);
    // if n is more than 19, divide it
    if (n > 19)
    {
        strcat(str,ten[n / 10]);
        strcat(str,one[n % 10]);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(str,one[n]);
    }
    // if n is non-zero
    if (n)
    {
        strcat(str,s);
    }
    return str;
}
// Function to print a given number in words
char* convertToWords(long n, char *out)
{
    char str[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    // handles digits at ten millions and hundred
    // millions places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords((n / 10000000), "million ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    // handles digits at hundred thousands and one
    // millions places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords(((n / 100000) % 100), "hundred thousand ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    // handles digits at thousands and tens thousands
    // places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords(((n / 1000) % 100), "thousand ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    // handles digit at hundreds places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords(((n / 100) % 10), "hundred ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    //Increase code readability
   
    // handles digits at ones and tens places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords((n % 100), "",str,BUF_SIZE));
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    //Get input number from user
    long num;
    char str[60] = {0};
    char s[10000];
    
    printf("Enter any number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &num);
    printf( "%s",convertToWords(num,str));
    
   
    return 0;
}
```

This will be the next line of code which will count the number of letters on the word form of a number.I am thinking of storing the value of convertToWords function to a variable then that variable will be an input for the following code. However equating convertToWords(num,str) to an array does not work. If there are other way two combine these two codes feel free to suggest. For example input of 100,  output must be 10 since there are ten letter in one hundred. Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //variable declaration
    char word[100];
    int a;
    int counting=0;
    int wordcountig=0;
    
    //Input word
    printf("Enter word to count the number of characters\n");
    //to read word from user
    gets(word);
    
    //to read characters 
    for(a=0; word[a]!='\0'; a++)
    {
        counting++;
    }
    for(a=0; a<counting; a++)
    {
        if(word[a]==32)
            wordcountig++;
    }
    
    //Display number of characters in the word
    wordcountig = counting-wordcountig;
    printf("\n\n The number of characters in entered word are : %d", wordcountig);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, both programs work, and you want to basically combine them and count the letters in the result of numToWords?

Comment: yess since only one program is needed

Comment: The first program does not work, it crashes because of out of bounds accesses all over the places.

Comment: it works on my end I have just tried it

Comment: `gets(word);` Did your compiler say something about it?

Comment: There is no efficient or compact way to equate all of the denomination of numbers from ones to tens to hundreds, ..., to bazillions into corresponding strings.  It requires brute force programming with lots of lines of code to define the _words_ that match up with the numbers.

Comment: _"it works on my end I have just tried it"_  Undefined behavior sometime appears that it works.  Writing out of bounds will only appear if the area in memory has already been allocated to some other process that you do not own.  If it all of the sudden _is_ allocated, then Bam!  Your program stops.  The problem with the OS is that it does not consult with you before it does stuff like that.  So it might work for you now, but it will eventually not .

Comment: @edmungvunxh https://godbolt.org/z/s9v3dYcYx here is the prove. It crashes in the line 35 `strcat(str,s);`. Even without that it would print `one million twenty three hundred thousand forty five thousand six hundred seventy eight ` instead of `twelve million three hundred forty five thousand six hundred seventy eight`

Comment: ahh sorry i only need conversion up to 5 digits because the maximum test case is 10000

Comment: If you only need conversions up to 5 digits, then why this ... `strcat(out, numToWords((n / 10000000), "million ",str,BUF_SIZE));`.  That information should be clearly provided in your post.  And the code shown should match your verbal descriptions.  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the resulting string in `str` in `main`. So, just use a loop to count the letters:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    if (isalpha(str[i]))
        ++count;
```

Here is the full program, including some fixes for buffer overflow (I increased the sizes) and for larger numbers:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 200
// strings at index 0 is not used, it is to make array
// indexing simple
char* one[] = { "", "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ",
                "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ",
                "nine ", "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ",
                "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ",
                "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ",
                "nineteen "
              };
// strings at index 0 and 1 are not used, they is to
// make array indexing simple
char* ten[] = { "", "", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ",
                "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ",
                "ninety "
              };
char * numToWords(unsigned int n, char* s, char *str, int len)
{
    memset(str,0,len);
    // if n is more than 19, divide it
    if (n > 19)
    {
        strcat(str,ten[n / 10]);
        strcat(str,one[n % 10]);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(str,one[n]);
    }
    // if n is non-zero
    if (n)
    {
        strcat(str,s);
    }
    return str;
}
// Function to print a given number in words
char* convertToWords(long n, char *out)
{
    char str[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    // handles digits at ten millions and hundred
    // millions places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords((n / 1000000), "million ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    // handles digits at hundred thousands and one
    // millions places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords(((n / 100000) % 10), "hundred ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    // handles digits at thousands and tens thousands
    // places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords(((n / 1000) % 100), "thousand ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    // handles digit at hundreds places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords(((n / 100) % 10), "hundred ",str,BUF_SIZE));
    //Increase code readability
   
    // handles digits at ones and tens places (if any)
    strcat(out, numToWords((n % 100), "",str,BUF_SIZE));
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    //Get input number from user
    long num;
    char str[600] = {0};
    scanf("%ld", &num);
    printf("%s\n",convertToWords(num,str));
    
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i) if (isalpha(str[i])) ++count;
    
    printf("It has %d characters\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/noh5bG36G

If you do not need the text output, you can change `printf( "%s",convertToWords(num,str));` to `convertToWords(num,str);`.